# Returning max and min from string of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

So I've created a short function to retrieve the `max` and `min` from a single string of integers. The string being as follows: `"1 9 3 4 -5"`.

My function returns it how I wish:

```
def high_and_low(nums):
    return f"{max(nums.split(' '))}" + " " + f"{min(nums.split(' '))}"


print(high_and_low("1 9 3 4 -5"))


>>> 9 -5
```

However when I change the string to `"4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"`, it doesn't return what I want at all! Instead it returns `6 -214` completely overlooking 542.

Why is this? What is happening under the hood?

Comment: after splitting you have to convert the numbers to int.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, this is not a bug problem it produces an output.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi There is no error (computer hardware or software). Please read the question again

Comment: Your function thinks the maximum number in `"4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"` is 6. That's an error/bug if I ever saw one.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi As shown above the code produces the correct output for one example and not for another and I asked why it happens. Not a bug

Comment: You compared the numbers as strings. With string comparison / alphabetic sorting the first character is the most important. "B" > "AAA" and "2" > "1000". The first example only worked, because all strings had the same length.

Comment: @Wups Ohhh ok. Didn't know that, thanks! That was the explanation I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting number strings to an integer.

```
def high_and_low(nums):
    nums_list = [int(i) for i in nums.split(' ')]
    return f"{max(nums_list)}" + " " + f"{min(nums_list)}"


print(high_and_low("1 9 3 4 -5")) # Output -> 9 -5
print(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")) # Output -> 542 -214
```

Comment: Cheers - that works. But why did the function work for the first example and not the second? If it worked for the first then seems okay?

Comment: @pragmaticlearner :  in your first example , it doesn't work, but it seen that it work. Because, min max are applied on strings, so the order will be alphanumeric order (lexicographic order).  A <B < C ....  and '1000000' < '200' because at first 1<2 ... look at [lexicographic order] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)

Answer (score 2):

I will explain why such behaviour was found.
As variable *nums* is a string, the statement

```
nums.split(' ')
```

will return a list of string as follows.

```
['1', '9', '3', '4', '-5']
```

Here each item is a string.
The [max()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#max) function will return the highest alphabetical character in a string.

ie. `max(nums.split(' '))` will return the `9`

To make it more clear,

```
string = "100008"
print(max(string))
```

will return 8. Because, 8 is the highest alphabetical character, in the string.

Just change the values of nums as follows:

```
nums = "1 63 8 3 4 -5"
max(nums.split(' '))
```

Now the output will be `8` instead of `68` .
This is because while dealing with strings, comparison happens in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), so every pair of characters is checked until it comes across a pair of unequal characters, and then the comparison of the two unequal characters is returned.

Here `'8'` is bigger than the first character `'6'` in `'63'`, so `'8' > '63'`

You got the correct answer when to converted to int because `max()` was able to determine the item as an integer, instead of treating each as a single character.

ie,

```
def high_and_low(nums):
    nums = [int(i) for i in nums.split(' ')]
    return f"{max(nums)}" + " " + f"{min(nums)}"

print(high_and_low("1 810 9 3 4 33 -9 -5 -1"))
```

Comment: _"This is because , while dealing with a list of strings, max() will only check the first character in each item"_ To be more precise, string comparison happens in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), so `'500' < '6'`, but `'500' < '510'`. To summarize: every character is checked until it comes across a pair of unequal characters, and then the comparison of the two unequal characters is returned.

Comment: Really understood the concept. But, why is the max() function only considering the first characters in the list.? Is there any other characteristics?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes. You are right. I will change that error statement.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I was also wondering, why the max() was dealing only with the first character. After doing some examples got the wrong potion .